# variable set to last value in for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the output of the following code.

```
var _list = [{id:0}, {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}];

function storeList() {
    for (var i = 0, j = _list.length; i < j; i++) {
        var key = makeKey(_list[i].id);
        _db.setValue(
            function() {
                console.log("OK: store a value of " + key);
            },
            function() {
                throw "ERR: can't store a value of " + key;
            },
            databaseName,
            key,
            _list[i]);
    }
}

storeList();
```

I expect it should output:

```
OK: store a value of 0
OK: store a value of 1
OK: store a value of 2
OK: store a value of 3
OK: store a value of 4
```

However, it outputs:

```
OK: store a value of 4
OK: store a value of 4
OK: store a value of 4
OK: store a value of 4
OK: store a value of 4
```

Why? and, what is the correct way to output?
I run this javascript code on Android Webview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a closure. You can do this by wrapping the code after key creation in a self executing function ([IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/))

```
(function(key) {
    db.setValue(
        function() {
            console.log("OK: store a value of " + key);
        },
        function() {
            throw "ERR: can't store a value of " + key;
        },
        databaseName,
        key,
        _list[i]
    );
})(key);
```

This is because the scope of `key` before was **visible** to **all** your iterated `setValue` calls. By using an `IIFE`, your passed keys scope is 'within' each `setValue` call.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, roughly I thought the reason could be this, but I thought maybe Javascript engine is smart to deal with this for developers.

Answer (score 1):

`db.setValue` is an async method. So when you call it, it detaches itself from main program flow while maintaining its access to loop counter `i`. Javascript always completes the current flow before executing any async code. So your loop runs 4 times, each time creating a block of async code that can only run after the currently executing program (for loop) is completed.

Note that each async block has the access to same `i`. Therefore, when it's time for them to execute, all they see is the value of i which exists after the main flow was completed (which in this case is 4).

With that in mind, the easiest way to deal with these problems is to create a closure. Basically, you'll give each async block a copy of i which will remain at the value it was when the block was created (unless your async block changes it). You can do that by iife as @AmmarCSE described. A cleaner way to approach is to move this stuff out in a method.

```
function setValue (i) {
    var key = makeKey(_list[i].id);
    _db.setValue(
        function() {
            console.log("OK: store a value of " + key);
        },
        function() {
            throw "ERR: can't store a value of " + key;
        },
        databaseName,
        key,
        _list[i]
    );
};

function storeList() {
    for (var i = 0, j = _list.length; i < j; i++) {
        setValue(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You step-by-step explanation is very clear!